# Can't use a declared variable outside of a switch statement

Tags: c#, integer, switch-statement

I declared a variable outside of the switch statement, then I added stuff to those variables inside a switch statement. After that, I tried using the variables outside of the statement, but it doesn't recognise the answers I already put in the variables.
Any ideas?

```
               int hp;
               int dmg;
               int dfn;
            switch (className)
            {
                case "Warrior":
                    Adventurer ch1 = new Adventurer(13, 40, 10);
                    dmg = ch1.damage;
                    hp = ch1.health;
                    dfn = ch1.defense;
                    break;
                case "Mage":
                    Adventurer ch2 = new Adventurer(17, 20, 3);
                    dmg = ch2.damage;
                    hp = ch2.health;
                    dfn = ch2.defense;
                    break;
                case "Druid":
                    Adventurer ch3 = new Adventurer(10, 30, 4);
                    dmg = ch3.damage;
                    hp = ch3.health;
                    dfn = ch3.defense;
                    break;
                case "Thief":
                    Adventurer ch4 = new Adventurer(20, 15, 1);
                    dmg = ch4.damage;
                    hp = ch4.health;
                    dfn = ch4.defense;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("There doesn't exist a class with that name, please try again:");
                    className = Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(hp);
```

Comment: `it doesn't recognise the answers` what do you mean by this? did you debug your code and see if proper case is executed and proper values are assigned to the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be getting error/warning for "**use of unassigned local variable**" as you have not initialized it. If this is the case then please assign values to local variable before switch

```
int hp = 0;
int dmg = 0;
int dfn = 0;
```